# Single AD user having 2 email addresses + SharePoint created 2 users

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync, ad

We are stuck in very difficult scenario.

We have a user U1 which has 2 email addresses in system U1@abc.com and U1@def.com

Now Sharepoint has 2 users for this

> i:0#.w|abc\U1
>
> i:0#.w|def\U1

Now in AD when user first name is updated it updates 1 Sharepoint account the other one remains as it is. The problem due to this is, when user logs on to intranet he is shown old first name.

When i try to search for user on Manage User Profile page. It doesn't show record for the non synced record

Kindly suggest what could be done.

Thanks

Comment: Does the user have 2 AD accounts? Are you using ADFS to log in?

Comment: Hi Gimzo, Thanks for the query.
The user has 1 account in AD for the user. We are not using ADFS.

Kindly let know if any further details required.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can force a resync with Active Directory info via SharePoint Management Shell:

```
Set-SPUser -Identity 'i:0#.w|def\U1' -Web http://test -SyncFromAD
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ff607827.aspx

Comment: Hi Steven,
Thank you for the pointer. I tried it, however no difference. another thing is when i try to search for user on Manage User Profile page. It doesn't show record for the non synced record

Comment: It DEF an alias for ABC? Is it a permanent situation that the user can log in with both usernames? Or is it an option to merge accounts with Move-SPUser (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx)